# Barrier Reverse Convertible on interest rate

Tags: interest-rates, finance, bond, derivatives

I'm trying to find the price of an barrier reverse convertible on interest rate - https://structuredproducts-ch.leonteq.com/isin/CH1251797945. I have simulated the underlying interest rate by Vasicek model, the expected value is above the barrier, so i will get the whole face value (1000 CHF). However, now i need to find the price of this derivative, my idea is that i just need to find the present value of the future cash flows (coupons + face value). Am i right? If so, what discount rate should i use? Could i use for example interest rates of swiss government bonds + some risk premium?
Thank you in advance for you answers.